# Send SMS if found changes in json file

Tags: javascript

I have this json file that I need to make a cron job for and receive SMS notification when data changes http://www.soyoustart.com/fr/js/dedicatedAvailability/availability-data.json

I need to find out if some server is on stock, so I found this code:

```
<?php

$cellphone = '15551234567';

$a_track = array('143sys12');

$s = file_get_contents('http://www.soyoustart.com/fr/js/dedicatedAvailability/availability-data.json');

$tmp = json_decode($s, true);
$a = $tmp ['availability'];

$data = array();

foreach ($a as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item ['reference'], $a_track)) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($item ['zones'] as $zone) {
        if ($zone ['availability'] == 'unavailable') {
            continue;
        }
        $data [$item ['reference']] .= $zone ['zone'];
    }
}

foreach ($data as $item => $availability) {
    $message = "SYS STOCK: $item: $availability";
    mail('my@email', 'OMG BUY THIS NOW!', $message);
    $url = "http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=xxxx&api_secret=yyyy&    from=nnnnnnnn&to=$cellphone&text=" . urlencode($message);
    $discard = file_get_contents($url);
}
```

The problem is that when I trigger it I receive SMS no matter if server is on stock or not and the SMSs keep coming with false positives. I also got this message :

```
]# /usr/bin/php /home/sys.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 143sys12 in /home/sys.php on line 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code around a bit and moved the sending of the message in a function to be called when the reference is found.

Take a look:

```
<?php

$a_track = array('143sys12');

$s = file_get_contents('http://www.soyoustart.com/fr/js/dedicatedAvailability/availability-data.json');

$tmp = json_decode($s, true);

foreach ($tmp['availability'] as $item) {
    if (in_array($item['reference'],$a_track)) sendMeAnEmail($item);
}

function sendMeAnEmail($item){
    $cellphone = '15551234567';

    $message = "SYS STOCK: ". $item["reference"] . PHP_EOL;
    $gotStock = 0;

    foreach ($item["zones"] as $zone) 
        if ($zone["availability"] != "unavailable" and $zone['availability'] != 'unknown' ) {
            $message .= "Available in the " . $zone["zone"]. " zone,  with the " . $zone["availability"] . " status." ;
            $gotStock++;
        }

    $url = "http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=xxxx&api_secret=yyyy&from=nnnnnnnn&to=$cellphone&text=" . urlencode($message);

    if ($gotStock > 0) {
        print $message . PHP_EOL; // to check 
        mail('my@email', 'OMG BUY THIS NOW!', $message);
        $discard = file_get_contents($url);
        print "Got stock, sent mail and SMS" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great ! The problem is that I still receive SMS when I trigger the code if server is 'unknown' status. I just received SMS with this text : "SYS STOCK: 143sys12 Avaiable in the rbx-hz with the unknown status".   I don't want to receive SMS if 'unavailable' or 'unknown'. Can you alter the code ?

Comment: updated the code, it's just a matter of adding to the condition and checking if you should send the mail+SMS or not, so I introduced the `$gotStock` variable